# Can't import sikuli modules from Sikuli IDE 1.0.0

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide

I'm using Sikuli IDE 1.0.0 on Mac, trying to get a simple test case working where I call a script in one module from another.
The modules are all in the same directory.

testModule.sikuli just has this:

```
from sikuli import *

def testFunc():
    exit(1)
```

testImport.sikuli just has this:

```
import testModule
reload(testModule)
testModule.testFunc()
```

running testImport just yields:
`[error] ImportError ( No module named testModule )`
on the import testModule line.

I've tried various additions to testImport including:

```
myScriptPath="[my project path]"
if not myScriptPath in sys.path: sys.path.append(myScriptPath)
```

None of these seem to work.

Comment: What is `[my project path]`? Is it the path to testModule.sikuli, or is it the path to the directory containing testModule.sikuli?

Answer (score 0):

I think the import just brings the new functions into the same module.

Try calling `testFunc()` instead of `testModule.testFunc()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue. I have solved this problem using classes.

Try this code:

testModule.sikuli:

```
from sikuli import *
class test:
    def testFunc(self):
        exit(1)
```

testImport.sikuli:

```
import testModule
foo = testModule.test()
foo.testFunc()
```

This should work assuming your files are in the same folder (for example ./test/testImport.sikuli and ./test/testModule.sikuli)